# Is there a way to keep track of objects clicked and display them as a message when the program ends in processing java?

Tags: processing

Im trying to create a small game where the user clicks randomly generated coins and I want it to keep track of how many they click. Also, I want this message to print out when I click the stop button on the processing window.

I tried using the exit() command as a public void, but that did not work.

Comment: Try something first and get back with a precise question and the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. You can check if the object is over a rectangle in the [`mouseClicked()`](https://processing.org/reference/mouseClicked_.html) even handler to increment your counter.

You *should* be able to override the [`exit()`](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#exit--) sketch function, however I noticed that it doesn't trigger when you use the stop button in the Processing IDE. It *does work* when you use the `ESCAPE` key to close the sketch. This might actual work better if you plan to export the sketch as an application (via File > Export Application).

Here's a super basic sketch to illustrated the above ideas:

```java
// dummy coin data
int[][] coinBoundingBoxes = {
  {30, 30, 30, 30},
  {135, 30, 30, 30},
  {250, 30, 30, 30},
  {30, 150, 30, 30},
  {135, 150, 30, 30},
  {250, 150, 30, 30},
  {30, 250, 30, 30},
  {135, 250, 30, 30},
  {250, 250, 30, 30},
};
// total number of coins clicked
int numClicks = 0;

void setup(){
  size(300, 300);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  // draw coins
  fill(255, 192, 0);
  for(int[] bbox : coinBoundingBoxes)
    ellipse(bbox[0] + bbox[2] * 0.5, bbox[1] + bbox[3] * 0.5, bbox[2], bbox[3]);
  // draw text
  fill(255);
  text(numClicks, 10, 15);
}

void mouseClicked(){
  // check if any coin is clicked to increment
  for(int[] bbox : coinBoundingBoxes){
    if(isInRect(mouseX, mouseY, bbox)){
      numClicks++;
    }
  }
}

// check is x,y are within bbox x,y,w,h (0, 1, 2, 3)
boolean isInRect(int x, int y, int[] r){
  return (x >= r[0] && x <= r[0] + r[2]) &&
         (y >= r[1] && y <= r[1] + r[3]);
}

// override exit to print clicks first
void exit(){
  println("total clicks: ", numClicks);
  super.exit();
}
```